# how to fix ClearInterval

Tags: javascript

I am working on the game. I have boards with cells. After clicking start, after 3s, the first cell lights up, then the next and next ... However, I would like only one cell to be lit on the board. This is my code:

```
let intervalId;
const start =  document.getElementById("start");
const reset =  document.getElementById("reset");

const cells = [].map.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName("board__box"),
  (currentValue) => currentValue
);

const cell = cells.map(cell => cell);

function setCellPosition() {
  const randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
  for( let j=0; j< cell.length; j++) {
    if(cell[j].getAttribute("data-row") == randomNumber && cell[j].getAttribute("data-column") == randomNumber) {
      cell[j].classList.add("check");
    }
  }
  console.log(intervalId);
}

function startInterval() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = setInterval(setCellPosition, 3000);
}

start.addEventListener("click", startInterval);
```

HtML code . divs with the `board__box` class I have 25

```
<div class="board">
    <div class="board__box" data-row="0" data-column="0"></div>
</div>
```

Why clearInterval does not work?

Comment: It *looks* like you're clearing all the intervals you're setting when initializing a new one, can you post the HTML so we have a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you are turning on your cells but you never turn off the turned on ones. (you never remove the "check" css class).
Something like this:

```
for( let j=0; j< cell.length; j++) {
    cell[j].classList.remove("check"); // added
    if(cell[j].getAttribute("data-row") == randomNumber && cell[j].getAttribute("data-column") == randomNumber) {
      cell[j].classList.add("check");
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks. I do not need clearInterval just another condition :)